# How to choose between 2 conflicting method prototypes?

Tags: c#, automapper

In AutoMapper, there is a class with these 2 methods:

```
void Condition(Func<ResolutionContext, bool> condition);
void Condition(Func<TSource, bool> condition);
```

When I write

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Prop, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.
```

Intellisense (in VS) proposes me the properties of ResolutionContext and if I type a property of my source class A, I get a compilation error because it expects a property of ResolutionContext.

What is the syntax in C# to choose between the 2 prototypes?

Thanks

Comment: Cast the parameters to a concrete type

Comment: @Gusman please show me, casting src seems impossible

Comment: Per example: Condition((Func<bool, bool>)((o) => true));

Comment: @Gusman ok it works but I'm puzzled by how VS (2015 here) manages that. When I typed the cast, it compiled but VS turned the cast to a greyed out color, saying that the cast was redundant. So I removed it. And guess what? What I typed manually before that was not compiling now compiles....

Comment: ...ROFL, ok, now I got no idea why that happened, maybe it's a bug on VS2015, or maybe you changed something and didn't realized

Comment: No I didn't. I can reproduce it. When you don't get the prototype you want, cast the param, let it gray out and remove it, and voila! Not very intuitive...